# How to replace fade transition by slide transition in a slideshow (javascript only)?

Tags: javascript, slideshow, transition, slide, fade

I am a JavaScript beginner. I  want to replace a fade transition with a  slide transition in a simple slideshow.

I have been unable to do so thus far. The current code is as follows:

```
function transSlide()
{
    nextSlide.style.display = "block";

    var opacity = slideTransStep / slideTransitionSteps;

    crtSlide.style.opacity = "" + (1 - opacity);
    crtSlide.style.filter = "alpha(opacity=" + (100 - opacity*100) + ")";

    nextSlide.style.opacity = "" + opacity;
    nextSlide.style.filter = "alpha(opacity=" + (opacity*100) + ")";

    if (++slideTransStep <= slideTransitionSteps)
        transTimeout = setTimeout("transSlide()", slideAnimationInterval);
    else
    {
        crtSlide.style.display = "none";
        transComplete();
        clearInterval(myVar);
    }
}
```

Comment: Never use `setTimeout` with strings, because then it uses the evil `eval`! Pass a function instead: `setTimeout(transSlide, ms);`

Comment: Welcome to SO @backward, cleaned up your question a little. Hope you get an answer soon!

Comment: Thanks for the answer.Could you give me a way?
I am really newbie in javascript.
Thnaks

Answer (score 1):

Intead of `opacity`, you want to change the `position` along with `top`, `left`, `bottom` and `right`, [see MDN documentation here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position).

That said, I think you could programm animations in JavaScript "by hand" for learning purposes, but you should normally use a library for stuff like this. There is [jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/category/effects/) and [jQuery UI effects](http://jqueryui.com/effect/) for starters.

**EDIT:**

Sure, I can help. I created a [CodePen](http://codepen.io/) with an very basic example for an animation. It uses `setInterval` to execute some code periodically and increase the CSS property `left` to move an element. You can check it out here: http://codepen.io/timbuethe/pen/wzIuA and even fork it to play with it.

Comment: Hi Tim,
Thnaks for the tip.
Is it possible to help me a little for this code? In order to learn a little ?
I know it's nothing but I really can't do it. Arf
Thanks for your help

Comment: Thanks so much Tim for your help.
I can't adapt my code with this (I don't arrive).

Comment: Can you adapt my code in order my slides sliding instead of fading.
I owe you a pint tho' buddy ;)

Comment: Hi Tim,
I made this :

function slideslide() {
    var num = 0, style = document.getElementById('container').style;
    window.setInterval(function () {
        // increase by num 1, reset to 0 at 4
        num = (num + 1) % 4;

        // -600 * 1 = -600, -600 * 2 = -1200, etc 
        style.marginLeft = (-600 * num) + "px"; 
    }, 3000); // repeat forever, polling every 3 seconds
}

I replace the name of the function too and still not works..
What is the problem?

Comment: Hi, I turned your code in a CodePen, see here http://codepen.io/timbuethe/pen/ytqJK. I also added an `alert` which displays a dialog with the current value, every time we set the marginLeft. I think you should find the error that way, right?

Comment: Hi Tim,
Thanks a lot for your help.
I hope I will find the error then.
I will try to adapt the code in your codepen for my slider.
I keep you inform.

Comment: Hey Tim,I have not find the solution to ADAPT IT with my **** code.
If I show you the whole code, could you try to fix it an explain me why doesn't work for me?
Cheerz

Comment: You should create a CodePen from your code and update the original question accordingly.

Comment: I found another Tim. Thanks so much for your time.
The code I found is JQuery based and called "BxSlider". Awesome slider 
with lot of control on it (css). I recomand it. Have a good one buddy